# TSQL in the Command object

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Please see the sub routine below:

```
Private Sub UpdateGrade(ByVal studentID As Integer, ByVal grade As String)
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim id As Integer
        Dim _ConString As String
        Try
            _ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ToString
            objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            objCommand = New SqlCommand("DECLARE @StudentID INT " & _
            "DECLARE @Grade char(1) " & _
            "SET @Grade = '" & grade & "'" & _
            "SET @StudentID = '" & studentID & "'" & _
            "If @Grade=1 " & _
            "begin " & _
            "update Student SET Grade = 'A' WHERE StudentID = @StudentID " & _
            "end " & _
            "Else If @Grade=2 " & _
            "begin " & _
            "update Student SET Grade = 'B' WHERE StudentID = @StudentID " & _
            "end " & _
            "If @Grade=3 " & _
            "begin " & _
            "update Student SET Grade = 'C' WHERE StudentID = @StudentID " & _
            "end " & _
            "Else If @Grade=4  " & _
            "begin " & _
            "update Student SET Grade = 'D' WHERE StudentID = @StudentID " & _
            "end")
            objCommand.Connection = objCon
            objCon.Open()
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try
```

Is there anything wrong setting the Command.CommandText to a TSQL statement? The TSQL looks like this (for readibility):

```
DECLARE @StudentID INT
DECLARE @Grade char(1)
SET @Grade = 
SET @StudentID = 
If @Grade=1 
begin
    update Student SET Grade = 'A'  WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
end 
Else If @Grade=2 
begin
    update Student SET Grade = 'B'  WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
end 
If @Grade=3
begin
    update Student SET Grade = 'C'  WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
end 
Else If @Grade=4 
begin
    update Student SET Grade = 'D'  WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
end
```

There is a call to UpdateGrade in a while loop.  The while loop, loops through five million students.  Please note that the live system is more complex for this,so I have provided the code above for illustrative purposes.

I have had issues calling stored procedures from .NET code in the past, which XACT_ABORT resolved.

Comment: Why arent you using a stored procedure....

Comment: @logixologist it is not necessary, or even IMO recommended, to call a stored procedure; please don't make it sound like "everyone uses stored procedures", because: they really don't

Comment: @logixologist, just for consistency.  The app does not use stored procedures at the moment.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, thanks.  Do you understand my question? After reading it a few times I am wandering if others will understand what I am getting at.

Comment: @w0051977, sorry if that came out wrong. The advantage you have is you can pass it a few parameters and do all your logic in a seperate file outside of your vb.net code. All you would need to do is set the commandtext to the storedprocedure. As far as the app not using them currently, I have been in positions numerous times where the app isnt and I still move all new code to sprocs so you can seperate the SQL from the .NET.  marc - I never said everyone uses them, I was only suggesting that it would work very well here.

Comment: @w0051977 I *kinda* understand your question, but all I can think is "yes, of course you can set the command-text to tsql; what *else* would you set it to?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *expected* that you set the command's `CommandText` to a TSQL statement, which you are already doing. I would, however, strongly advise against this bit:

```
        "DECLARE @StudentID INT " & _
        "DECLARE @Grade char(1) " & _
        "SET @Grade = '" & grade & "'" & _
        "SET @StudentID = '" & studentID & "'" & _
```

that should be removed, with just (sorry for C# semi-colons; force of habit):

```
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID", studentID);
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Grade", grade);
```

which is then safe from SQL injection.

Also, maybe a `select case`, i.e. (using C# for the example):

```
objCommand.CommandText = @"
    update Student set Grade = select case @Grade
            when 1 then 'A' when 2 then 'B'
            when 3 then 'C' when 4 then 'C'
            else Grade end
    where StudentId = @StudentID";
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID", studentID);
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Grade", grade);
```

Comment: Thanks.  The app in question is a VB6 app.  The reason I have provided a .NET example is because .NET code tends to reach more people on here (IMO).  I suppose the same applies to VB6? +1.

Comment: @w0051977 shudder; you just took me back many years to my vb6 days; now, you need to be careful because vb6 is not the same as .net, and in particular ado is not the same as ado.net - especially with parameters. ADO in vb6 *can be parameterized*, but it might work differently.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last sentence: "it might work differently".  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 also, in other news: vb6 - will that zombie *not stay dead* yet? for the love of everything, *please* consider updating. Pretty please.

Comment: @w0051977 IIRC (and I emphasize: this was a *long* time ago) - ADO defaults to parameters by index, not name? although that might *only* be when calling sprocs; you'd need to test it

Comment: Thanks.  I have asked another question here geared towards SQL and data warehouses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111928/java-net-developer-moving-towards-data-warehouse.  Please take a look if you have time.